# Neat way of computing functions on key-value pairs

Tags: data-structures, dictionary

Suppose you have a have list with key - value pairs. Neither
keys, nor values, nor the pair are required to be unique.

The following example

```
a -> 1
b -> 2
c -> 3
a -> 3
b -> 1
```

would be valid.

Now suppose I want to associate to any key value pair (k->v) another value V,
which has the following properties:

- it is the same for two pairs, if their keys are identical
- it is uniquely determined by the set of key-value pairs in the entire list

This sounds abstract, but for example the sum, the maximum and counting function qualify as examples

```
 Pair    SUM    MAX  COUNT
a -> 1    4      3     2
b -> 2    3      2     2
c -> 3    3      3     1
a -> 3    4      3     2
b -> 1    3      2     2
```

I am looking for a fast methods/data structures to compute such functions on the entire list.

If the keys can be sorted, one can simply sort the list, then iterate through the sorted list, and compute the function V in each block with identical keys.

I am asking whether there are nice methods to do this, if the values are not comparable or one does
not want to change the order of the entries.

Some thoughts:

1. Of course, one could apply a hash function to the keys, in order to obtain sortable keys.
2. Of course, one could also store the original position of each pair, then do the sorting, then compute
   the function, and finally undo the sorting.

So essentially the question is already answered. However, I am interested in whether
there are more elegant solutions maybe using some adapt data structure

EDIT: To clarify Sunny Agrawal comment, what I mean by associate. Well this is also part of the question on how to nicely arrange the data structure.
In my example, I would get another list/map  with (k->v) as key  and V as value. However, it might make sense to not arrange the data that way. I require, that V is stored in such a way that for given k it needs constant time to obtain V.

Comment: what do you mean by associate with the key value pairs ?
one solution is to maintain a another DS is parallel which is a map containing the key as original Data and value is a structure of Min, Max, Count, Sum, Avg etc and you update the structure for each key as you add

Comment: It is not about language, but about the structure. So be it java or c++, or c#. The answer should not depend on that

Comment: @SunnyAgrawal Sure that would be possible, but also slow. If your list is n entries long, your method would need touching/updating O(n^2) entries. This is slower than using the method with sorting.

Comment: @wood If N is no of elements in list and M is no of unique keys in the list then complexity of my solution is N*log(M) which is less than sorting N*Log(N), because updating map will not be O(N)

Comment: @SunnyAgrawal I do not understand your argument. Could you please elaborate a bit more. Maybe as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain 2 DS

```
1. List< Pair< Key_Type, Value_Type > >
2. Map<Key_Type, Stats>
```

where Stats is struct as follows

```
struct Stats
{
    int Sum;
    int Count;
    int Max;
};
```

First DS Contains all your key,val pairs in the order you want to store,
Second maintains the data stats for each key as shown in your example

Insert will work as follows(Pseudo C++ Code)

```
void Insert(key,val)
{
    list.insert(Pair(key,val))

    Stats curr;
    if(map.contains(key))
    {
        curr = map[key];
        curr.Max = Max(curr.Max, val);
        curr.Count++;
        curr.Sum += val;
    }
    else
    {
        curr.Max = val
        curr.Count = 1;
        curr.Sum = val;
    }
    map[key] = curr; 
}
```

Complexity will be O(1) for updating list and O(lgM) for updating map
where M is no of unique Keys and
if N is total no of objects in list
Total time in inserts will be O(N) + O(NlogM)

Note: this will work if we have inserts only, in case of deletions, Updating Max will be difficult